# Apps in my google-play-console are not available in the search after 10K+ downloads

Tags: google-play-console

We have an account in the playstore that published more than 50 apps everything works fine but this December something an expectedly changed All our apps are not available in playstore search
I know new Apps aren’t usually come top of the app search but [this App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.data.saamionline) isn’t new and has already downloaded 10K+ but it's not showing in the search even if I scroll down to bottom [image]

Most of our apps have more reviews and downloads but I don’t know what’s going on.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: It's the first one I see when I search for it

Comment: I don't know but all I see is that above image @Lemon

Comment: Maybe you have edited something to do with geolocation/country blocking that’s stopping your country from seeing your app possibly?

Answer (score 0):

after the new Google Play Console surely something updated automatically geolocation.
All our apps are unavailable for 21 countries containing  Somalia and Djibouti  (a country I live) is part of that unavailable list.

All I do is update the list of Countries/Regions in the production to make apps available to all users

Thank you @Lemon for your comment